# How to force change Network site multi language subdirectory base URL?

Tags: multisite, multi-language, plugin-wpml, network-admin

I have enabled network site and created two sites. Then I enabled **WPML** plugin on both sites.

1) First one is for English and all **LTR** languages. This one is working fine because it's base URL is like `myweb.example.com`. And other languages URL becomes like  `myweb.example.com/fr`, `myweb.example.com/ru` etc.

2) Second one site is created for **Arabic** and all **RTL** languages. However the problem is that it's base URL is set to `myweb.example.com/ar/`. So now if someone wants to access another RTL language let say URDU so the URL become  `myweb.example.com/ar/ur`.

So the problem here is that in Arabic website it appends the language code to the base URL (`myweb.example.com/ar/`) but my requirements are if someone want to see it in URDU it should be like `myweb.example.com/ur/` not like `myweb.example.com/ar/ur`. So how can I do that?

Comment: Why have 2 separate sites?